# how to create a button which leads to data.prevPage in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I want to manually create a button that leads to the previous page.

This is all ok:

```
newButton = $("<a href='" + $prevPage + "' title='back' data-rel='back'>" + someText + "</a>").buttonMarkup({
    shadow: true,
    corners: true,
    theme: "a",
    iconpos: "left",
    icon: 'arrow-l'
    });
```

My problem is setting the *$prevPage* variable. The data object supplied by JQM contains a *prevPage* object, so my question:

How do I extract the URL or Hashchange from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most use something like this -

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="back" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

You shouldn't have to extract a hash using this method.

Comment: mh. Don't want to mess with history.go(-1)... I'm looking at $.mobile.path.parseUrl( ) now, but I'd still need the URL. Mh. Not there yet :-)

Comment: What do you mean "mess with"? You put the markup in and you're done.

Comment: I have three panels with pages inside and I need to make sure, I'm going back on the correct panel. Also (not sure here) I have set this up alongside JQM, so if a user clicks the button this will trigger the regular JQM (forward transition) plus a hashChange I'm triggering manually. The forward transition is blocked and the hashChange should do the backwards transition. Should... :-)

Comment: The problem is, I have a wrapper page id="wrap" containing three panels A/B/C each with two JQM pages id="one/two/three" and "one-2/two-2/three-2". If I change on panel A from "one" to "one-2", history and JQM history will contain "wrap" "one-2", so if I go(-1), I'm not going back from "one-2" to "one" on panel A. Therefore I need the URL/ID of prePage, so I can intercept on pagebeforechange and redirect

Comment: You should have included all of that in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) method:

`<a href='javascript:history.back();' title='back' data-rel='back'>`

Answer (score 0):

The pagebeforeshow documentation doesn't say a ton about the prevPage object, and it's nontrivial so they should probably update it, but after some digging in Chrome's debugger, I believe I've found what you (and I) are looking for.

`prevPage` is techinically an array of HTMLDivElements. The most recent one is the 0th element, so in order to access the object itself, you need `data.prevPage[0]`. From there you can get access to pretty much anything on the previous page (`data.prevPage[0].innerHTML` is literally a copy of the entire page - don't ask me why). The easiest way is probably to take the previous page's ID, or `data.prevPage[0].id`, and do something with it (seeing as you should know what your page titles are from the IDs).

If not, you can scrape the innerHTML for the title itself. The entire code block would look something like this:

```
$('#yourPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data) {
  var ID = data.prevPage[0].id;
  // do something with ID
});
```

Comment: hey. this is nice! Let me check.